# multiple conditions check with dataframe rows using if elif .. checking today's points and yesterdaypoints

Tags: python

Friends,
I have a simple requirement to compare the two separate rows ( current day and previous day using SHIFT). I am comparing current day reference points with previous days multiple points. Followed is the snapshot of excel table ( just for reference, i want to do calculations in python only).

My python code is followed.

```
#calculate Low Travel point
    df['1back'] = df['low'].shift(1) 
    if  df['low'] < df['N400_Z2'].shift(1): 
        df['TP_low'] = 'zz2'
    elif df['low'] > df['N400_Z2'].shift(1) and df['low'] < df['N300_Z'].shift(1):
         df['TP_low'] = "Z1"
```

And I am getting followed error.
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

[image: Sample reference points]

Answer (score 0):

So I was taking a deeper look and it seems the desired behavior can be accomplished with the pandas where() method (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), which takes a boolean array and where that array is **false** it substitutes with the specified value. Because the substitution happens when the boolean array is false, I had to add negative signs before each filter to keep the desired conditions from your post.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(15,4), columns=['low', 'N400_Z2', 'TP_low', 'N300_Z'])

#calculate Low Travel point
df['1back'] = df['low'].shift(1)

filter_ = df['low'] < df['N400_Z2'].shift(1)
filter2_ = (df['low'] > df['N400_Z2'].shift(1)) & (df['low'] < df['N300_Z'].shift(1))

df['TP_low'].where(-filter_, 'zz2', inplace=True)
df['TP_low'].where(-filter2_, 'Z1', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hi! Leo, No I am getting the same error as above

Comment: worked like a champ! Leo.. Thanks, followed is my output... more filters more clear    Datetime                                                                 
2020-12-17 08:30:00       NaN  3250.000000  3263.510010    NaN     NaN   
2020-12-17 08:45:00       NaN  3252.239990  3259.399902     J2     NaN   
2020-12-17 09:00:00       NaN  3252.175049  3255.250000      W     NaN   
2020-12-17 09:15:00       NaN  3230.777344  3247.840088     J1     NaN

Answer (score 0):

Followed is the answer.. Thanks to Leo...
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(15,4), columns=['low', 'N400_Z2', 'TP_low', 'N300_Z'])

#calculate Low Travel point
df['1back'] = df['low'].shift(1)

filter_ = df['low'] < df['N400_Z2'].shift(1)
filter2_ = (df['low'] > df['N400_Z2'].shift(1)) & (df['low'] < df['N300_Z'].shift(1))

df['TP_low'].where(-filter_, 'zz2', inplace=True)
df['TP_low'].where(-filter2_, 'Z1', inplace=True)